# moment js invalid date from masked input text

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Im trying to validate a birthdate with moment js, but i cant do it.
Im using this code:

```
dateIsBefore(date) {
      return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    }
```

and this is my masked input element:

```
<el-input
                  class="date-input"
                  type="tel"
                  v-mask="'##/##/####'"
                  placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"
                ></el-input>
```

but it return me a false value, when i expecting a true. The moment object say the date is invalid.

Im getting the date from an input text (is a masked input date) with the format '28/04/1990'.

Comment: Why are you passing a **string** into `isBefore` when you already have a Moment?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here:

```
dateIsBefore(date) {
  return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
// --------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

You already have a Moment (from `moment()`), just use it directly, don't convert it to a string:

```
dateIsBefore(date) {
  return moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment());
}
```

That definitely makes more sense, and the reason I think it may solve your problem is that if you pass a string in to `isBefore`, Moment has to parse the string. Without knowing the format, faced with a string in the form `##/##/####` it's almost certainly going to use the (somewhat bizarre) U.S. format, which is `MM/DD/YYYY` because that's what browsers do (even outside the U.S.) when faced with that kind of string.

Passing in a Moment means you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the input parameter for the method **dateIsBefore** is in the format of ***DD-MM-YYYY*** this is not the valid date format.Your date format should be ***MM-DD-YYYY*** and you doesn't want to format the moment functions

[Date time string format](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)

[image]

**Use this method for the date format 'DD-MM-YYYY'**

```
function dateIsBefore(date) {
 const dateInput=date.split('-') //use this line of code the input is in the format 
  of 'DD-MM-YYYY'
 return moment(`${dateInput[1]}-${dateInput[0]}-${dateInput[2]}`).isBefore(moment());
}
```